# Trouble grouping files with Python

Tags: python-2.7, grouping, create-directory

So, my main goal is to have this make directories based on the amount of (files//2000)+1 and put 2000 files in each directory and whatever is leftover into the final directory (assuming it'll never be divisible by 2000 evenly).

So far, my scripting looks like this:

```
import os
import shutil

def createDirs():'
src='P:\\stuff
folderNumber=0
filesNumber=0
for files in os.listdir(src):
    filesNumber=filesNumber+1
print filesNumber
totalFolders=(filesNumber//2000)+1
print totalFolders
for folders in range(0, totalFolders):
    os.mkdir('P:\\Project\\User\\TEST\\folder' + str(folderNumber))
    folderNumber=folderNumber+1

def group():
fileType='.txt'
src='P:\\Project\\User\\files'
folderCount=0
fileCount=0
for folders in os.listdir('P:\\Project\\User\\TEST'):
    folderCount=folderCount+1
for files in os.listdir('P:\\Project\\User\\TEST\\folder' + str(folderCount)):
    fileCount=fileCount+1
while fileCount <= 2000:
    for file in os.listdir(src):
        if file.endswith(filetype):
            path = os.path.join(src, file):
            shutil.move(path, 'P:\\Project\\User\\TEST\\folder' + str(folderCount))
```

The directories get made, the files move to folder one, but files just keep flowing into folder 1 endlessly.

Any help and/or ways to improve this process would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

in your `while` statement you never increase `fileCount` or `folderCount`. I would probably remove the while statement and replace it with:

```
for name in os.listdir(src):
    if name.endswith(filetype):
        fileCount += 1
        if fileCount > 2000:
            fileCount = 0
            folderCount += 1
        path = os.path.join(src, file):
        shutil.move(path, 'P:\\Project\\User\\TEST\\folder' + str(folderCount))
```